# Multiple application instances and FileLock

Tags: java, file, operating-system

Will multiple instances of the same Java application respect file locks made by 'java.nio.channels.FileLock' on the same OS? Let's say on the same computer or a server. (Java 17.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in the Javadoc for `FileLock`, specifically the section on "Platform Dependencies".

This is completely implementation defined, so you have to study the underlying OS to see if file locks are enforced. All you can be certain of is that any Java program will use the same underlying file locking mechanism, and that underlying mechanism defines the behavior.

Also, in most systems, file locking is collaborative, meaning everybody has to use the file locking mechanism to participate. Code that doesn't lock files may or may not get access to files locked by other processes. And of course, things get much more complex when you have networked filesystems, so "your mileage WILL vary".

Comment: But I'm not talking about some other processes/apps, but other instances of the same app